# PyQGIS script change version to QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am new in python 3 and I have a question, I have a script in QGIS 2.8 and is working, but my problem is in QGIS 3 the next part of script read the file but don't add the new line in each row.

```
import os
import numpy as np

os.chdir(r'C:\IDW_v3')    
file="HP.txt"    
HP = np.loadtxt(file, dtype='float')    
np.savetxt('HP_2_np.txt', HP, fmt='%10.5f', delimiter=' ')
```

Result in 2.8
[image]

Result in version 3

[image]
Any idea?

Comment: That's not about QGIS, maybe numpy or python version.

Comment: Can you recommend a change or another way of reading the text file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not about QGIS, maybe numpy or python version. QGIS 2 uses Python 2.7, QGIS 3 uses Python 3.6.

`delimiter` parameter adds string/character seperating columns. If you don't specify `newline` parameter, I guess, numpy doesn't add newline character in Python 3.

So use in that way:

```
np.savetxt('HP_2_np.txt', HP, fmt='%10.5f', delimiter=' ', newline='\r\n')
```

Output:

```
    1.00000   2.00000   3.00000
    4.00000   5.00000   6.00000
```